# Passing a typedef from header to source - C

Tags: c, data-structures, typedef, ansi-c

I have the following **main.c** file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wctype.h>

#include "lista.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct nod *root = NULL;
    root = init(root);

    return 0;
}
```

And **lista.h**:

```
#ifndef LISTA_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTA_H_INCLUDED

#include "lista.c"

typedef struct nod
{
    int Value;
    struct nod *Next;
}nod;

nod* init(nod *);
void printList(nod *);

#endif // LISTA_H_INCLUDED
```

And finally **lista.c** which is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include "lista.h"

nod* init(nod *root)
{
    root = NULL;
    return root;
}

void printList(nod *root)
{
    //We don't want to change original root node!
    nod *aux = root;

    printf("\n=== Printed list =====\n");
    while (aux != NULL)
    {
        printf(aux->Value);
        aux = aux->Next;
    }
    puts("\n");
}
```

Even after included header file, I'm getting three errors which say:
**Unknown type name 'nod'**

How to make that typedef from lista.h to be seen on lista.c?

I just can't figure out what is happening here.

Comment: Remove the `#include "lista.c"` from `lista.h`. It's pulling in all the `lista.c` content (referencing `nod`) before it gets to actually define `nod`. And in general, `.h` files never include `.c`. It's the other way around.

Comment: never include C files as a rule. Neither in headers nor in sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your **lista.h** header file:

```
#ifndef LISTA_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTA_H_INCLUDED

#include "lista.c"

[..]

#endif // LISTA_H_INCLUDED
```

You're including **lista.c**, which you shouldn't do at all. And the error occures, because at that time `nod` isn't defined yet.